# Birt: change the dimension of chart through script

Tags: javascript, birt

Can someone please tell me how to change the dimension of a chart through javascript in Birt. I tried the below method but the chart totally disappears after I put the below script in beforegeneration event of chart

```
function beforeGeneration( chart, icsc )
{
    yAxis = chart.getAxes()[0].getAssociatedAxes()[0];
    seriesDef = yAxis.getSeriesDefinitions()[0];
    for(i=0;i<seriesDef.getSeries().size();i++)
    {   
        if(seriesDef.getSeries()[i].getSeriesIdentifier() == "My Town")
        {       
            ds = seriesDef.getSeries()[i].getDataSet(); 
        }
    }
    ns = BarSeriesImpl.create();
    ns.setDataSet(ds);
    ns.setSeriesIdentifier("My Town");
    seriesDef.getSeries().add(ns);
    seriesDef.getSeries().move(0,ns);
    setDimension(TWO_DIMENSIONAL_WITH_DEPTH_LITERAL);

}
```

The whole function is working. Only problem I am facing is to change the chart type to 2D with Depth. I have problem with below syntax

```
setDimension(TWO_DIMENSIONAL_WITH_DEPTH_LITERAL);
```

Any help will be appreciated

Arif

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it the following instead....

chart.setDimension(actuate.report.Chart.CHART_DIMENSION_2D_WITH_DEPTH );